# Wordpress Gutenberg withSelect get list of post types

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am using Gutenberg's withSelect package to try to get all of the post types belonging to the site. Here is my code:

```
export default withSelect( select => {
    // shorthand
    const { getEntityRecords } = select( 'core' );

    return {
        typesList: getEntityRecords( 'types', '' ),
    };
} )( SearchEdit );
```

But I am not getting anything back. I also found the documentation for withSelect very sparse so if anyone has any further information that would be great and I will try to update the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Know it has been a while since this was asked, but I had this come up today so here is an answer. There is a method called `getPostTypes()`, see the example below:

```
export default withSelect( select => {
    const {getPostTypes} = select('core);

    return {
        typesList: getPostTypes(),
    }
} )( YourEdit );
```

Note: `getPostTypes()` will return an array of post type objects. If you want just the names, you will need to process the results into the desired format.

Comment: @rhysclay I inspected the results of `select('core')`. There are also methods for taxonomies and taxonomy terms among other useful items.